# In EF 6 Code first how do I create a many to many bi-directional link with each side being an aggregate but one side owning the links?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following scenario: Two aggregate entities, Entry and Tag. They have a many to many relationship, with neither side owning the other side, but Entry needs to own the link between Entry and Tag. Basically a tag will continue to exist even if all the entries linked to it go away, and an Entry should only create/delete the linkage itself, it shouldn't try to persist the Tag, either in creation or deletion.

So far I haven't found a way to do this in EF 6, but most of my experience has been in Java and Spring Data/Hibernate.

```
public class Tag : AbstractEntity{
        //public User User { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        [InverseProperty("Tags")]
        public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries {get; private set;}

        protected Tag() { }
}

public class Entry : AbstractEntity
{
    public string Desc { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }
    [InverseProperty("Entries")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected Entry()
    {
    }
}
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>().HasMany<Tag>(x => x.Tags).WithMany(x => x.Entries).Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("EntryId").MapRightKey("TagID").ToTable("EntryTag"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly but from what I understand what you are trying to do is break a database principle. From a db perspective you cannot have a many to many relationship where the one is reliant on the other. What I would suggest is a nullable FK on Entry to tag but then one Tag can have multiple Entries but an entry can only have one Tag (or none). I am not sure if you can make a collection (m-2-m) nullable in EF or if that would even help.

Comment: Basically when I add/delete a link to Entry I want to to create/delete a row in the EntryTag table, but I don't want it to create a new row in the Tag table if the tag doesn't exist. I would rather the db throw a FK error. Basically you shouldn't be able to add in new tags through an Entry object.

Comment: EF has no mechanism for that, EF is created to help you to do that kind of operation for you in the interest of time saving. You will have to manually check for such events. You can override the SaveChanges method and check if the tag was created through a navigation property or explicitly. It will add overhead but it is the only way you will be able to accomplish this..To my knowledge at least